I want to bound the entries of the matrix $\mid A^{-1} \mid \mid A \mid$
I want to show that the entries of the matrix multiplication $\lvert A^{-1}\rvert \lvert A \rvert$, where $A\in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ are less than one. The absolute value in $\lvert A \rvert$ is  taken entry-wise, i.e., if we let $B=\lvert A \rvert$ then $b_{ij}=\lvert a_{ij} \rvert$, $1\leq i,\,j\leq n$.
Some properties of matrix A:

$A$ is an entirely positive matrix entry-wise, i.e., $\lvert A \rvert=A$, but its inverse is not an M-matrix if that's relevant here.
$A$ is a symmetric positive definite and hence invertible.
The entries of the inverse $A^{-1}$ are not necessarily positive and hence $\lvert A^{-1}\rvert \neq  A^{-1}$ otherwise the answer would have been straightforward.

My matrix could have some additional properties but I am not sure what to look for in my matrix since I don't know which technique would be used to prove what I want to prove, I would gladly answer any questions and provide any extra information that could facilitate the way to answer.
I would appreciate any help and even references to where I should look. Thanks in advance!

By $B=|A|$ you mean $b_{ij}=|a_{ij}|$? Easy to confuse your question with something about the condition number of A where $|A|$ means some norm of $A$.

Hi Paul! Yes, that's the intended meaning. The entry-wise absolute value. I will edit it now to make it more clear. Thanks for pointing this out.

For $0<\delta<1$, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \delta \\ \delta & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ is symmetric, positive definite with strictly positive entries. The eigenvalues are $1\pm \delta$. The inverse is $$\frac{1}{1-\delta^2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-\delta\\-\delta&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ If we multiply $|A^{-1}||A|$, the first entry is $\frac{1+\delta^2}{1-\delta^2}$. Not only is this always greater than $1$, it's unbounded as $\delta\uparrow 1$.
